# CSS of a parent table of a Div with ID =? that is the table above said div id but not direct parent

Tags: css

CSS of a parent table of a Div with ID =? that is the table above said div id but not direct parent

Any ideas...

I have tried `[id*="reserveEmail"] {`

Comment: You can't do that; CSS cannot select a parent based on it's children.

Comment: Do you mean a sibling rather than parent?

Comment: What about table:has(> #reserveEmail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)